# Text data assert with configFile

Tags: automation, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm writing a Cypress with POM. I want to put assert texts/messages in a textdata.json/txt so that i won't populate page class with too much texts/information. I have tried different approaches such as;

```
cy.get("element")
  .readFile('cypress\fixtures\testData.json')
  .should("have.text", variable name from json file)
```

or

cy.get("element")
.should("have.text", this.data.variable name from json file)

with before-function but didn't work.

Any idea of how i can get this to please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, you don't want to use `page class` which I guess is fair when you are trying to find the right balance between DAMP and DRY principles. I can suggest the following minimal usage of texts/messages:

**a. Use import instead of readFile**

cypress/fixtures/testData.json:

```json
{
 "text": "variable name from json file"
}
```

cypress/integration/spec.js (test file):

```js
import * as testData from '../fixtures/testData'

cy.get("element").should("have.text", testData.text)
```

**b. Use fixtures instead of readFile**

cypress/fixtures/testData.json:

```json
{
 "text": "variable name from json file"
}
```

cypress/integration/spec.js (test file):

```js
cy.fixture('testData').then((data) => {
 cy.get("element").should("have.text", data.text)
})
```

**c. Use a customised POM / selector file:** (I use this heaps on my projects)

cypress/pages/loginPage.js:

```js
export const testDataModel = {
 text: "variable name from json file"
}
```

cypress/integration/spec.js (test file):

```js
import {testDataModel} from '../pages/loginPage'

cy.get("element").should("have.text", testDataModel.text)
```

Comment: Option B works out perfectly for me unlike option A. I will try option as well too. Thank you  so much Ebanster.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest and least fragile way is to add the texts to the `Cypress` object.

```js
before(() => {
  cy.readFile('cypress\fixtures\testData.json')
    .then(data => Cypress.texts = data);
})

it('tests with testData', () => {
  cy.get("element").should("have.text", Cypress.texts.myElementText)
})
```

The fixture file is read only once and is not cleared by the Cypress runner between tests (which is what happens to local variables).

Just make sure you don't name them the same as a property that Cypress already uses (`console.log(Cypress)` to check).

You can also do it globally (for all specs) by moving the `before(() => cy.readFile...` into **cypress/support/index**.